# 500 ошибка при импорте модулей в файл __init__.py

Tags: python, apache, flask, telebot

Всем привет. Только начинаю осваивать Python и взаимодействие с серверами. Столкнулся с одной проблемой, которую не могу решить уже второй день. У меня есть сервер Debian, на который я установил Apache и Flask. Пытаюсь получать параметры из URL адреса, при обращении на сервер, а затем передать их в Telegram. Сделал настройку согласно этой крутой инструкции https://www.8host.com/blog/razvyortyvanie-prilozheniya-flask-na-servere-ubuntu/

Все работает прекрасно, пока я не пытаюсь импортировать в файл **init**.py любые модули, например import telebot или requests. После добавления модулей, я регулярно получаю 500 ошибку. У меня есть подозрения, что файл **init**.py не предназначен для написания кода, а только для его инициализации. Тогда возникает вопрос, как я могу добавить другие файлы.py в эту систему, чтобы они корректно работали.

Для настройки сервера, я использую следующиую последовательность команд:

[Forwarded from Свой Человек]

1. Установить Sudo
   apt install sudo
2. Обноваить пакеты
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt upgrade -y
3. Установка пакетного менеджера pip
   sudo apt install python3-venv
4. Установка Apache
   sudo apt install apache2
5. Установка брандмауэра UFW
   sudo apt install ufw
6. Разрешаем SSH подключение
   sudo ufw allow ssh
7. Открываем 80 и 443 порты
   sudo ufw allow 'WWW Full'
8. Включаем UFW фаервол
   sudo ufw enable
9. Проверяем SFTP на доступность
10. Проверка сервера Apache
    sudo systemctl status apache2
11. Установка mod_wsgi
    sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi python-dev
12. Запускаем mod_wsgi
    sudo a2enmod wsgi
13. Переходим в директорию WWW
    cd /var/www
14. Создаем каталог
    sudo mkdir FlaskApp
    cd FlaskApp
15. Создаем еще один каталог в этом
    sudo mkdir FlaskApp
16. Создаем еще 2 подкаталога
    sudo mkdir static templates
17. Создаем файл скрипта .py
    sudo nano **init**.py
18. Добавляем код в файл

    from flask import Flask
    app = Flask(name)
    @app.route("/")
    def hello():
    return "Hello, I love Digital Ocean!"
    if name == "main":
    app.run()
19. Устанавливаем pip для Python3
    sudo apt install python3-pip
20. Устанавливаем virtualenv
    sudo pip3 install virtualenv
21. Создаем в этой папке виртуальное окружение
    sudo virtualenv myvenv
22. Запускаем виртуальную среду myvenv
    source myvenv/bin/activate
23. Устанавливаем Flask
    sudo pip3 install Flask
24. Проверяем работу
    sudo python3 **init**.py
25. Настройка виртуального хоста
    sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/ReplaceApp.conf
26. Добавляем в файл следующие данные

    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 138.124.187.85
    ServerAdmin admin@138.124.187.85
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi
    <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

    Alias /static /var/www/ReplaceApp/ReplaceApp/static
    <Directory /var/www/ReplaceApp/ReplaceApp/static/>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Сохраняем и закрываем.
Директория:
cd var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp
source venv/bin/activate
28. Включение виртуального хоста
sudo a2ensite FlaskApp
29. Создание файла .wsgi
cd /var/www/FlaskApp
sudo nano flaskapp.wsgi
30. В файл сохраняем следующие данные

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/FlaskApp/")
from FlaskApp import app as application
application.secret_key = 'Add your secret key'
```

31. Перезапускаем Apache
    sudo service apache2 restart

Код, который работает ниже:

```
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def postback():
    username = request.args.get('username')
    if username != "":      
        
        return username


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Код который не работает ниже:

````
from flask import request
import telebot
import requests


bot = telebot.TeleBot("1507501961:AAFi0lwzOKpVIQux4liBKuB2g7WUf5He8VM")

app = Flask(__name__)

chateid = "348103174"

@app.route('/')
def postback():
    username = request.args.get('username')
    if username != "":      
        bot.send_message(chateid, text=username)
        return username         

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()```
````